# PHP code not outputting what I need it to. How can I fix this?

Tags: php, html

I posted the other day with errors that I needed help fixing and it seems that I have got them fixed but I ran into another issue. My code is made to take user inputs for an invoice and when they click submit I want it to output 'This Invoice is %y years, %m months, and %d days. I can't seem to get my code to work correctly and output this. I included both my index.php code and the data_tester.php code that I am using.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
$action =  $_POST['action'];
} else {
$action =  'start_app';
}

switch ($action) {
case 'start_app':

    // set default invoice date 1 month prior to current date
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
    $default_date = new DateTime();
    $default_date->sub($interval);
    $invoice_date_s = $default_date->format('n/j/Y');

    // set default due date 2 months after current date
    $interval = new DateInterval('P2M');
    $default_date = new DateTime();
    $default_date->add($interval);
    $due_date_s = $default_date->format('n/j/Y');

    $message = 'Enter two dates and click on the Submit button.';
    break;
case 'process_data':
    $invoice_date_s = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'invoice_date');
    $due_date_s = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'due_date');

    // make sure the user enters both dates
    if (empty($invoice_date_s) || empty($due_date_s)){
        $message = 'You must enter both dates. Please Try Again.';
        break;
    }

    // convert date strings to DateTime objects
    // and use a try/catch to make sure the dates are valid

    try{
        $invoice_date_o = new DateTime($invoice_date_s);
        $due_date_o = new DateTime($due_date_s);
    } catch (Exception $e){
        $message = 'Both dates must be in a valid format. Please check and try again';
        break;
    }

    // make sure the due date is after the invoice date

    if ($due_date_o < $invoice_date_o){
        $message = 'The due date must come after the invoice date. Please check the information and try again.';
        break;
    }
    $format_string = 'F j, Y';
    // format both dates
    $invoice_date_f = $invoice_date_o->format($format_string);
    $due_date_f = $due_date_o->format($format_string);


    // get the current date and time and format it
    $current_date_o = new DateTime();
    $current_date_f = $current_date_o -> format($format_string);
    $current_time_f = $current_date_o -> format('g:i:s a');

    // get the amount of time between the current date and the due date
    $time_span = $current_date_o ->diff($due_date_o);
    if ($due_date_o < $current_date_o){
        $due_date_message = $time_span ->format('This Invoice is %y years, %m months, and %d days.');
    }

    // and format the due date message

    break;
 }
 include 'date_tester.php';
 ?>
```

Date_tester.php code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Date Tester</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content">
    <h1>Date Tester</h1>
    <form action="." method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="process_data"/>

    <label>Invoice Date:</label>
    <input type="text" name="invoice_date"
           value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($invoice_date_s); ?>"/>
    <br />

    <label>Due Date:</label>
    <input type="text" name="due_date"
           value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($due_date_s); ?>"/>
    <br />

    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <br />

    </form>
    <h2>Message:</h2>
    <?php if (!empty($message)): ?>

        <p><?php echo $message; ?></p>
    <?php else : ?>
    <table cellspacing="5px">
        <tr>
            <td>Invoice date:</td>
            <td><?php echo $invoice_date_f; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Due date:</td>
            <td><?php echo $due_date_f; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Current date:</td>
            <td><?php echo $current_date_f; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Current time:</td>
            <td><?php echo $current_time_f; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Due date message:</td>
            <td><?php echo $due_date_message = isset($due_date_message) ? $due_date_message : ""; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What needs to be done so when I click submit the output shows how long until the invoice is due.

Comment: Well, for some reason that if condition `if ($due_date_o < $current_date_o)` evaluates as `false`. Have you tried printing out those two variables, to see if they actually contain what you expect them to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know logic of your statement, but for your example, it works well if I reverse this condition below:

Original : `if ($due_date_o < $current_date_o)`

New: `if ($due_date_o > $current_date_o)`

We can see `$due_date_o` is a `DateTime` with value `2020-04-27 00:00:00.000000` and with your rules it must be greater than `$current_date_o` that has value `2020-02-27 23:24:43.184785`.

Comment: I can't believe I messed that up. :facepalm:

That was the issue I had once I changed the sign the other way it worked as expected. Thanks so much for pointing that out for me I was struggling to figure it out.